# Show portion of Bitmap image on canvas in Android

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, bitmap, drawbitmap

I am trying to build a Magnify tool in my Android app. For this, I have an ImageView, which I converted to Bitmap (with some zoom/scale factor).

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap drawingCache = imageView.getDrawingCache(true);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(5, 5);        

Bitmap viewCapture = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingCache, 0, 0, 
                                         drawingCache.getWidth(),
                                         drawingCache.getHeight(), 
                                         matrix, true);
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Now, I am drawing this Bitmap image "viewCapture" to my canvas. Here, I want only portion of the image to be rendered on the canvas.

I tried using approaches: "setRectToRect() on Matrix", "canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, paint)". But, didn't work out appropriately.

Would using SurfaceViews be helpful? Has anyone come across this situation? Please post your thoughts/ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the following?

```
 Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

`src` corresponds to which region of the bitmap you want to draw and `dst` says where you want the bitmap drawn.  You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: When I do that, I get a smaller image of the bitmap, instead of cropped image.

Comment: Actually, I am scaling the image before creating the Bitmap. And, when I do use this method, I lose the associated density.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Paint%29

Answer (score 0):

When I do that, I get a smaller image of the bitmap, instead of cropped image. Following is the snippet I have used.

```
            Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawRGB(10, 10, 10);              
            Rect src = new Rect((int)x - _image.getWidth(), (int) y - _image.getHeight(), (int)x + _image.getWidth(), (int) y + _image.getHeight());
            RectF dst = new RectF((int)x - 50, (int) y - 50, (int)x + 50, (int) y + 50);
            c.drawBitmap(_image, src, dst, null);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```